# How to pass a string variable with spaces to bash function

Tags: string, bash

I want to pass a string variable with spaces as an argument to my function. But the string after spaces is not included. Can anybody help me out with this?

```
ABC(){
var1="$1"
var2="$2"
echo "$1"
echo "$2"
} 

def() {
V1="aaaa"
v2="bbb ccc"

ABC $v1 $v2 
} 

Def
```

Output I get is

```
aaaa
bbb
```

While I expect:

```
aaaa
bbb ccc
```

Why does the string after space is not included

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters

Comment: Running your script through shellcheck would tell you what the issue is, btw.

Comment: @aayanrade : Please post scripts only, which actually would run. For instance, you are invoking a command `Def`, which would result in an error '_bash: Def: command not found_', since you didn't define a function or file of this name.

Answer (score 2):

Please change this line:

```
ABC $v1 $v2
```

into:

```
ABC "$v1" "$v2"
```

Apart from that, shell script is case sensitive. You have wrong case in your variables, e.g. `V1` in `def` function, and `def()...` and `Def`